# Multiple Regression Line Interpretation

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a regression model analysis for a set of data. I am trying to determine a regression line from this set of data, it is multiple regression. I am having trouble determining the line of regression. I have attached a picture of of my regression analysis.[image]

Comment: Are you just looking for what the prediction equation is?

Comment: @Dason so for a single regression it would be Y = b0 + b1x. But with multiple regression, it is different and that is what Im having trouble with.

Comment: Yeah there are multiple inputs. So it would be like Y = b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + ... + bn*xn where the "xi" represent the different variables and the "bi" represent the estimated coefficients.

Comment: @LukeHarding the estimates are the coef. i.e. (intercept) is b0, num_people is b1, num_records is b2 etc.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: So would it look something like this: Y = 21.18 + -.003x_1 + .43x_2 + .02x_3 + .0003x_4 + .002x_5 + .110x_6? But I feel like thats not correct?

Comment: @LukeHarding And why do you feel that way?

Comment: It seems a little too easy honestly

Comment: Nobody said it had to be hard

Comment: Oh okay cool, thank you for the help!

Comment: This is not a programming question. If you have questions about interpreting statistical models, you should ask at [stats.se], not here.

Comment: There are plenty of R questions on here and it is a type of coding

Answer (score 0):

The answer goes to OP:
You can take values from `Coefficients` sections of `summary` and make an equation of regression hyperplane as follows:  `Y = 21.18 + -.003x_1 + .43x_2 + .02x_3 + .0003x_4 + .002x_5 + .110x_6`.